# Why do web sites replace unicode chars with images?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Recently I installed the NoScript plugin in firefox to control the execution of javascript. I noticed that some websites use some fancy unicode charaters as place holders for images, which are replaced with images once I allow javascript. One example site is github.com, see the screenshot which was taken before I enabled javascript.

What's the advantage of this instead of simply place the image directly in html or css?

[image: Screenshot of a github repo with the fancy unicode chars are highlighted. I censored some stuff because it is not my repo...]

Comment: the advantage: to place icons as-needed w/ clean markup instead of using long-winded URLs inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sites are using an icon font (or more than one).

An icon font is a regular font file that contains images. It's a technique to cut down on HTTP requests and to enable some other features.

Now, how or why that's defeated by the NoScript plugin, I don't know. (*edit* — it's apparently a configurable NoScript option, which is selected by default. All `@font-face` rules are blocked, ostensibly for security reasons.)

In  your GitHub sample, a quick trip into the developer tools shows that there's a font called "octicons".

Comment: adblock can hit some fontawsome icons (the branded ones), maybe this is related? (just stopping JS doesn't break the font/icon)

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple - these strange symbols are markers where images should be placed instead of character symbols (obviously, so far). If JavaScript is enabled, during the load process a specific JS function will be triggered and all such markers will be replaced with images.

Now the tricky part - if the browser can't load/execute JavaScript, then either JavaScript has been disabled (case 1), or there is significant network latency (case 2) and the browse request has timed out.

In the second case we don't want to burden the user with additional images, since most likely these images will take forever to load. Therefore, we do the process incrementally:

1. We load the basic web page with image markers instead of real images.
2. JavaScript hook is triggered **after** the basic web page has been fully loaded. At this point all non-critical images are requested behind the scenes by JavaScript calls.
3. All such images are loaded asynchronously and since the basic web page has already been loaded, the user doesn't experience any latency whatsoever, even if one or more images fail to load.

Well, that's it!

Comment: Though something like this is possible, it's not what's happening in the case of the site used as an example in the question.